# Como usar order_by especial do mysql no codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

no mysql eu posso fazer assim.

```
SELECT * FROM `Cidade` ORDER BY `id`=1347 DESC
```

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer no codeigniter, estou tentando assim:

```
$this->db->order_by("id = 1347", "DESC")
                ->get("Cidades");
```

Neste caso a saída dele está sendo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `Cidade` ORDER BY `id=1347` DESC
```

ele está colocando um bloquote na expressão inteira. aí não funfa.
Desde já agradeço a ajudar.

Comment: Já tentou fazer assim:
`order_by("`id`", "1347", "DESC")`

Comment: pq tem aquele número? não seria apenas o nome da coluna?

Comment: order_by("id", " = 1347 DESC")

Comment: é o id. Serve para colocar algumas cidades mais importantes no topo. exemplo, Fortaleza é a capital, mas na ordem natural ela fica lá pelo meio. Gostaria que ela ficasse no topo, porque será a mais utilizada. O mysql aceita esse tipo de order_by, mas não to conseguindo fazer isso no codeigniter. Já tentei esse order_by("id", "1347", "DESC"), mas não rola, acho que vou ter que escrever a sql mesmo.

Comment: Aqui funcionou exatamente como você está querendo
$c = $this->db->order_by("id = 1347 DESC")->get("Cidade");
var_dump($c->result_array()). Você pode testar para mim e ver se é alguma coisa relaciona com a versão?

Comment: Assim não funfou. ele retornou isto: `SELECT * FROM \`Cidade\` ORDER BY \`id =\` 1347 DESC` ele poe o = no bloquote

Answer (score 1):

A solução que eu encontrei foi escrevendo a sql, não é a melhor forma mas funcionou. se alguém tiver uma forma melhor.

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `Cidade` 
                                ORDER BY id = 1347 DESC
                                , id = 1156 DESC
                                , id = 1284 DESC
                                , id = 1337 DESC
                                ");
```

Valeu!

Comment: Tem algumas querys que é melhor escrever dessa forma mesmo, o Active Record do Codeigniter não esta preparado para todo tipo, não tem nenhum problema em fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

No último parâmetro do método [order_by](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results) coloque FALSE, para que o texto digitado seja incluído sem alteração no que foi escrito, ou seja, os dados não serão escapado, exemplo:

```
$this->db->order_by("id = 1347", "DESC", FALSE)
```